# C# Finding top-level window

Tags: c#, windows, pinvoke

How to find top-level window if I have child handle?

**EDIT:**
For example, I'm trying to get handle of play button in WindowsMediaPlayer12.
I thought I can get main handle of window (WMP window) with GetForegroundWindow() and then find play button in its children... In most cases GetForegroundWindow() works and I get handle of whole focused window, but sometimes (and in this case) it just returns handle of window's currently focused child.
So, in this case GetForegroundWindow() returns handle of player's upper part and play button is not one of it's child. I would like to know how to get handle of the whole player?

**EDIT2:**
Example 2: Open Opera browser and click in address bar. Call GetForegroundWindow(). You will get handle only of that part of Opera window instead of **whole Opera window that is displayed**. Try to list children of that handle. There are no children.
(**bold** is the handle that I'm looking for.)

Comment: You are going about this the wrong way entirely. Your original question was, "how do I find top-level window if I have child?" Your update now asks, "how do I find child it I have top-level window?" A completely different question. If you want to play music then why don't you ask a question about that. Nice and easy to answer, and for sure it won't involve any of the things that you think it will involve.

Comment: I'm not trying to play music. This is just an example. If you read carefully you will see that GetForegroundWindow() in this case is not top-level, because then I could get handle of play button.

Comment: You picked an application that does not use normal windowed controls.

Comment: Seams like there is a lot of this type application (Opera browser, Visual Studio...). I just want to know how can I get handle of a complete window that is in foreground and not only it's part in this cases.

Comment: I still cannot understand the question. You've asked two diametrically opposite questions. I'm confused.

Comment: I don't know how to better explain this problem. You can read example 2.

Comment: So just do what I said in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep calling [`GetParent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633510.aspx) until `NULL` is returned.

Comment: GetParent(GetForegroundWindow()); returns 0 in every case I've tried, so only GetForegroundWindow() should work in every case but it works in some cases, and in some not.

Comment: If `GetForegroundWindow()` is not `0`, and `GetParent(GetForegroundWindow())` is `0` then you've found the top-level window.

Comment: Ok then, that is the answer. But this didn't solve my problem. I still can't get all children from application window.

Comment: You seem to be very mixed up between children and parents. Do note that applications like WMP and Opera have very unusual windowing hierarchies. To understand them better use a tool like Spy++. I also suggest that the automation API is a probably a better way to proceed.

Comment: The suggestion "Keep calling GetParent until NULL is returned" is not reliable. I wrote a program that tested this technique vs "hWndTop:= GetAncestor(hWnd,GA_ROOT)" against every window under GetDesktopWindow.  GetAncestor always worked. In Windows 10, GetParent failed for 115 out of 656 windows. In Windows 11, GetParent failed for 93 out of 320 windows. Many top level windows have parent windows.

Answer (score 2):

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

public enum GetAncestorFlags
{
    GetParent = 1,
    GetRoot = 2,
    GetRootOwner = 3
}

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr GetAncestor(IntPtr hwnd, GetAncestorFlags gaFlags);

IntPtr wHandle = GetForgroudWindow();
IntPtr rootHandle = GetAncestor(wHandle, GetAncestorFlags.GetRoot);
```

rootHandle should be the top-most window for the process.  From there you can traverse the children to find the child you are looking for.

Comment: This works perfectly for me when using `WindowFromPoint` and passing the resulting pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried working with the WindowInteropHelper class ?

IntPtr windowHandle = new WindowInteropHelper(myWindow).Owner;

IntPtr windowHandle = new WindowInteropHelper(myWindow).Handle;

Edit:

Now that your question is edited, I think your solution can be to dive from the main window handle down, instead of from the focused control and up.. try:

`Window mainWindow = Application.Current.MainWindow`